# How to remove the virus: "fun.xls.exe"

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

I found that on my pendrive, there is a file called:

```
fun.xls.exe
```

And VirusTotal says:

https://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=6752376c0e3e56d65ad86f1fa377987c9e666e76bbe0e78328fab86091c621fb-1314718022

That it's a virus.. great..my AntiVirus software: Comodo Internet Securiy didn't said that it's a virus.

How can I get rid of it??? :\

Comment: Microsoft Security Essentials.  Free, fast, made by Microsoft.  'Nuff said.

Comment: @Breakthrough I saw you to prefer the MSE but I have used it and it scans very slow but no doubt its consume very small amount of memory.

Comment: @avirk that's not necessarily a bad thing - MSE usually flags stuff some other AVs won't, so I assume it uses some different detection techniques, which might take a bit longer, but provide much more accurate virus detection rates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the combofix or you can boot time scan using [Rescue CD](http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd) provided by AVG which works for me.

You can also use AVAST antivirus it has an option to scan at boot time. There is no better scan than Boot time.